# What could possibly make a C++ program crash in ntdll.dll?

Tags: c++, access-violation

My Windows C++ program is behaving worse than ever. It crashes spontaneously, usually just when/after a function returns anything. The fault module indicated is, at times the program itself, at times ntdll.dll, at times StackHash_something and the exception code is at times access violation, at times 40000015. This has driven me crazy. I've seen this crash one time occuring just after assigning a value to a certain variable, and not occuring anymore if I commented the line that did that assignment (and occuring elsewhere...).

Yet I am unable to trace the problem... Any hints?

A piece of code from my actual program, to exemplify what I said (although I doubt it can be very helpful):

```
void Propozitie::AdaugaConstructieIncidenta(wstring text)
{
// Some function that creates/updates a member in a "Propozitie" object
// constr_incidenta is Entitate*, member of "Propozitie"
// p is a wstring, member of object "Entitate"
delete constr_incidenta;
constr_incidenta = new Entitate;
constr_incidenta->p = text;
// ^ app crashes here.
//had it been constr_incidenta->p = L""; it wouldn't have crashed
}
```

UPDATE: I reinstalled Windows, GCC and everything. I get the same unexplainable error! Maybe a hint would be that the assignment takes place just after the program has executed a set of recursive functions which create some objects on the way...? I'm desperate.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour. Code is needed.

Comment: "It crashes spontaneously, usually just when/after a function returns anything." Sounds like stack or general memory corruption to me. Check all array accesses and make sure you aren't going out of bounds with any indices.

Comment: How is the `constr_incidenta->p` getting a copy of the `wstring text`?  Is `constr_incidenta->p` getting a pointer to memory owned by `text`?

Comment: what is the type of constr_incidenta->p? and can you show the code that is calling this function?

Comment: `constr_incidenta` is a pointer to an object of type Entitate. The `p` member of `Entitate` is an actual wstring. The code above may not be so relevant, since I sometimes get such strange crashes after a silly function returns an `int`... The code calling the function is nothing special, `some_prop->AdaugaConstructieIncidenta(L"some_text");`

Comment: but, without code, people can't suggest anything... Can you show some code that is using the string Entitate::p? Are you going out of bounds for this variable?

Comment: No, I'm certainly not going out of bounds for any variable. I create lots of objects inside some recursive functions right before calling this function, is there any chance that they could bring up the problem? :| I doubt, because at times the program successfully executes this function but crashes at a further point... Maybe the program is messing the OS's memory?

Comment: I just discovered that an older version of the program, which I had no problems with at its time, has the same errors. I've decided to reinstall windows on that machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem in my project. It was a circular function call in the end. Maybe make sure in your recursion that you don't accidentally do circular calls or overflow the call stack.

I wanted to leave a comment but i don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to re-evaluate all of your code. I assume this is a large code base that you can't just post here, but usually you get these kind of errors when memory starts getting corrupted because you are writing and/or reading outside the bounds of initialized memory.

Comment: I don't consider this option anymore, the same problems happened to me some days ago and in desperation I deleted hundreds of lines of code, which I wrote again from scratch; now I get the same problems. A hint might be that this error occurs inside and sometimes right after a set of recursive function calls (not deep enough to cause trouble, though) which also create some objects in the memory. Yet I don't understand why should this be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does Entitate have a default constructor?  If not, it will not be initialized when you call "new Entitate".

Comment: It didn't have. I've just written one for it and I get the same problems.